# getting all records with same foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm working on my first project in Django/Postgres, an app to track plant breeding projects. I have a `Generation` model that connects to a `Project` model with `ForeignKey` (i.e., each breeding project consists of multiple generations of offspring):

```py
class Generation(models.Model):
   # ...
   project = models.ForeignKey(
     Project, 
     related_name="generations", 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE
     )
```

I'd like to add a `generation_number` field that auto-increments based on the associated project - if there are already 3 records with the same foreign key in the Generation table, then the next record created with that FK should get assigned a `generation_number` of 4. My understanding is that I can't use an `AutoField` because this is not a primary key, so I'm trying to write a method that counts the number of records with the same FK and adds 1, something like:

```py
def increment_gen_number(self):
  last_count = Project.objects.filter(pk=self.project).count()
  return last_count+1

gen_number = models.IntegerField(default=increment_gen_number)
```

I'm guessing there are some syntax issues since I'm still new to Python and this feels like a bit of a kludge. How can I get this to work?

Comment: In my opinion, the right approach is to use post_save and post_delete [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) to keep the counter up to date. Read about signals and, if for you is also a solution, I can write an answer with this approach.

Comment: I think this is the approach I want to take. Just to make sure I understand properly, this would listen for the creation of a new record, then count the number of records with the same `Project` FK and update the record with a new `Generation.gen_number`?

Comment: I posted an answer using signals. Also, a test to illustrate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use signals to keep your field up to date:

```py
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):   
   n_generations = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Generation(models.Model):
   project = models.ForeignKey(
     Project, 
     related_name="generations", 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE
     )

# Signals
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import F


@receiver(post_save, sender=Generation)
def add_project(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        return
    project = instance.project
    project.n_generations = F('n_generations') + 1
    project.save()
    project.refresh_from_db()

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Generation)
def rm_project(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    project = instance.project
    project.n_generations = F('n_generations') - 1
    project.save()
    project.refresh_from_db()
```

Test passes:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from ppapp.models import Project, Generation

class ProjectTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Project.objects.create()

    def test_animals_can_speak(self):
        """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
        p1 = Project.objects.all()[0]

        g1 = Generation(project=p1) # +1
        g1.save()
        g2 = Generation(project=p1) # +1
        g2.save()
        g3 = Generation(project=p1) # +1
        g3.save()
        g4 = Generation(project=p1) # +1
        g4.save()
        p1.generations.create() # +1
        g6 = Generation(project=p1) # +1
        g6.save()
        g6.delete() # -1
        
        self.assertEqual(p1.n_generations, 5)
```

```
(venv) dani@localhost ppp $ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.017s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method on your Generation model, and so do the logic that you want.

put this on your model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # your logic
    super(GeeksModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```